# How to group flex-children and show them in a different direction?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, media-queries

I'm new to flexbox, and I can't find a solution for my problem.
I have a label, an image, an input, and an image in a paragraph. I added `display:flex` to my paragraph which aligns my images to the input very nicely.

```
<p style='display:flex'><label>
    <image><input><image>
</p>
```

When my resolution is to small I want to center my content and put the label above my input like this:

```
<p><label>
<MINUS-image><input><PLUS-image></p>
```

I added `flex-direction: column` to my paragraph (and do some centering-stuff to my label) when my resolution is below 600px. But then everything is in a column.

```
<p><label>
<MINUS-image>
<input>
<PLUS-image></p>
```

Is there a way to group my images and the input, to keep them in one line?

Comment: Yes, there is `media query` but you have to provide us with your code so we can suggest you the best way for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of change to `column`, use `flex-wrap: wrap` and give the `label` a width of 100%.

Using the media query, and on narrower screens, this will make the `label` take full width of its parent, the `p`, and push the other elements to a second row, instead of stack them all vertically, as `column` does.

Stack snippet

```css
p {
  display:flex;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  p {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  p label {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  <label>Label</label>
  <span>image</span>
  <input>
  <span>image</span>
</p>
```

Comment: That works great for me. Thank you!

In addition, I altered the media query:
I added "justify-content: center;" to the p, to get my images and input centered.

Comment: @MarianSchrader Sounds great...and add `text-align: center` to the `label` rule and you'll have its text too centered